# Efficient way to compare large,uneven 2d lists [Python]

Tags: python, list

I have two lists that I created by parsing two large (4GB+) files. What I was looking for in the files was ID and sequence pairs. The following is a simple version of how the files were created:

```
tmplst=[]
lst=[]
for record in file_parse:
    ID, sequence = record
    tmplst=[ID,sequence]
    lst.append(tmplst)
```

The `lst` structure looks like this: (all elements in the list are in string format)

```
[['ID1','sequence1'],
['ID2', 'sequence2'],
['ID3', 'sequence3']]
```

What I want to do is compare the two lists by ID by ID. If there is a ID match between two lists, I want to append the sequence for that ID to a new list, else I want to append -1 to the new list

The following is a basic code representation:

```
list1_2_comparison = []
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    if list1[i][0]==list2[i][0]:
        list1_2_comparison.append(list2[i][1])
    else:
        list1_2_comparison.append(-1)
```

Let's suppose `list1` is bigger than `list2`, which means that all of the IDs in `list2` are in `list1` but not all IDs in `list1` are in `list2` (at least, in my files that is the case). I have encountered two issues experimenting with the code above:

1.`IndexError: Index out of range` 
and, when I replace the `len(list1)` to `len(list2)` in for loop, it gives no error but:

2.`The code keeps running forever and is **never** executed (I am guessing thats due to the large file size but I'm no expert so I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do it)`

I hope I have provided enough info for the problem. If there are any issues with my question, please let me know.

Comment: 1) new list should be '1d' one? I mean there is to be either sequence or -1 only and nothing else? 2) if there is a match is there only one sequence? two lists has the same `sequenceNumber` in the same id?

Comment: try this `[i[1][1] if i[0][0]==i[1][0] else -1 for i in zip(list1,list2)]` does it work?

Comment: #Yes, new list should be 1d, containing either the sequence or the -1 in case no match.

Comment: If there is a match, I'd like to append the sequence of list2 only. The two list have the same IDs. Like I said the bigger list, list1, has all the IDs and the list2 is a subset of it i.e. it contains the same IDs as list1 but not all of them, that's why it is shorter in length.

Comment: The code you mentioned is running but there's an issue. I have written another program to get the total number of IDs from each file. The difference is 129, list2 has 129 less IDs than list1. Again, list2 is derived from list1, it has IDs that are not present in list1.

Comment: From your code, the number of times '-1' is appended in the new list of 30k+.

Comment: the sequences of the some ID (from different lists) are always the same? or you need to append the seq from list2 only because it differs from corresponding seq from list1?

Comment: the line I provided does the same thing that 'The following is a basic code representation:' snippet does. but maybe I get you wrong, and you needn't to just compare two lists by indices (list1[0] - list2[0], list1[1] -list2[1] .. etc). maybe what you need is to get list with elements exactly like list1 but element should be seq from list2 if there is ID match, and if there is no ID match element should be '-1', am I right?

Comment: Apologies for the SUPER late reply but yes you are right (about ur last sentence above).